# Parse URL and create Links On Plain-Text Jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, template-engine

I am getting plain-text in which there could be a URL.

**For Example**
: learn abc in one day www.englishspeaking.com

Here I am having a URL. I want to convert it has a link. I am using Jade template engine. Is there a way to do this in Jade template engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use already build npm for this. Like this, I found [anchrome](https://github.com/alexcorvi/anchorme.js) and its also worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Use `markdown` filter like this

```
:markdown
  this is the start of the para.
  [a link](http://example.com)
  and this is the rest of the paragraph.
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Using my example, I can do like 
:markdown
[a link]( learn abc in one day www.englishspeaking.com)?

Comment: @MAS1112 try like this: learn abc in one day a(href='www.englishspeaking.com') here

Comment: It will work. I have to parse url from text first. Ok, it get it :) .. Let me also wait for others, to contribute.